# substring with a small change

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to solve this problem were they give me a set of strings where to count how many times a certain word appears within a string like 'code' but the program also counts any variant where the 'd' changes like 'coze' but something like 'coz' doesn't count this is what I made:

```
 def count(word):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(word)):
    lo=word[i:i+4]
    if lo=='co': # this is what gives me trouble
      count+=1
  return count
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. It sounds like you just need to match the regular expression `co.e`

Comment: sounds like you might need fuzzy matching

Comment: One letter can be different in any position or **only** the *third* position?  Is `cede` OK? Is this a homework/school problem?  What is wrong with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Test if the first two characters match `co` and the 4th character matches `e`.

```
def count(word):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(word)-3):
    if word[i:i+1] == 'co' and word[i+3] == 'e'
      count+=1
  return count
```

The loop only goes up to `len(word)-3` so that `word[i+3]` won't go out of range.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for this, through the `re` module.

```
import re
string = 'this is a string containing the words code, coze, and coz'
re.findall(r'co.e', string)
['code', 'coze']
```

from there you could write a function such as:

```
def count(string, word):
    return len(re.findall(word, string))
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is the answer to your question as mentioned above but what you need is a more refined regex pattern. since you are looking for **certain word appears** you need to search for boundary words. So your pattern should be sth. like this:

```
pattern = r'\bco.e\b'
```

this way your search will not match with the words like `testcodetest` or `cozetest` but only match with `code` `coze` `coke` but not leading or following characters

if you gonna test for multiple times, then it's better to use a compiled pattern, that way it'd be more memory efficient.

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: string = 'this is a string containing the codeorg testcozetest words code, coze, and coz'

In [3]: pattern = re.compile(r'\bco.e\b')

In [4]: pattern.findall(string)
Out[4]: ['code', 'coze']
```

Hope that helps.